# Finding the group of three cells with the highest average (Need help to optimize the formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The goal is ( it's simpler than it sounds ) :

**To find a group of three cells (say, A1, A2, A3 or A20, A21, A22) that has a highest average in the column, and get the position of the cell in the middle of that group.**

I already have formulaS that allow me to find the result.
However, I need to do it in one line without using another column for calculations.

I use the column beside to find the group of cells with highest AVG using this formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1>AVERAGE(A1:A51), A2>AVERAGE(A1:A51), A3>AVERAGE(A1:A51)), SUM(A1:A3), 0)
```

Then, in the cell below the column for calculations, I'm looking for the row with the highest value:

```
=MATCH(MAX(C1:C51),C1:C51,0)
```

**Is there a way to combine these formulas in one line, so all calculations can be done in one cell?**

You can check this google sheet to see how it was done:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yBvF4xMI5fblL5_F8dGONl4BfBHgXHyEWDh6zXV3RMg/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the image of the sheet:
[image]

Comment: And if Excel, Office 365 with access to `SCAN()` or `BYROW()`?

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @P.b If I recall correctly, I downloaded Office365 during the installation, but this is just a regular Excel

Comment: Is that `AND` formula drag filled down?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, it is

Comment: Wouldn't the A2:A51 become A3:A53 on the second row?

Comment: @BigBen The question is for Excel. I used Google sheets just for sharing purposes

Comment: @TheMaster Well, I wrote the formula in C2 cell, since this way it finds the position of the row correctly, otherwise, with drag fill it produce errors, since it would need inexistent cell A0 and empty cell A52

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Office 365 you could use

```
=LET(maxaverage,BYROW(A1:A51,LAMBDA(r,AVERAGE(OFFSET(r,,,3)))),
XMATCH(MAX(maxaverage),maxaverage)+1)
```

The BYROW function used in combination with LAMBDA makes it possible to make a calculation row by row over a range.

Since you want to calculate the average of 3 cells in a row, I used OFFSET to loop the average through given range with the height offset of 3.

So the first average will be the first cell in the range including the following 2 cells.
The second references the second cell in the range including the following 2, etc.

In the end that results in a spill range (an array) of all the averages. I used LET to name that calculation `maxaverage`.

I could then reference that word in the function instead of recalculating it.

I then used MAX to get the maximum value in `maxaverage` and MATCH to get the position of the max value from `maxaverage` within `maxaverage`.
That's the top cell of the 3, so I added `+1` to get the middle position.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You are a genius! :) 
I literally don't know any of the keywords that you used. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @theMaster (& Reg Box) I added explanation which I think explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

in google sheets try:

```
=INDEX(SORT({ROW(A1:A51)+1, BYROW(IF((
 QUERY({{"";"";A1:A51}, {"";A1:A51;""}, {A1:A51;"";""}}, 
 "offset 2", )>AVERAGE(A1:A51))={TRUE, TRUE, TRUE}, 
 QUERY({{"";"";A1:A51}, {"";A1:A51;""}, {A1:A51;"";""}}, 
 "offset 2", ), ), LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))}, 2, ), 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution for GOOGLE SHEETS! Works flawlessly!